# How to pass button to anonymous callback function in onclick?

Tags: javascript, this

I used to have a button like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="SaveReleaseStage(this, 'Reassigned', 'ReleaseStage/ReassignProcess');" />
```

where the "this" being passed was the button. Everything worked great.

When I changed it to this:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="ShowConfirmation('Confirm', 'Some message...', function () { SaveReleaseStage(this, 'Reassigned', 'ReleaseStage/ReassignProcess'); });" />
```

the "this" is now the Window object and not the button.

Is there a way to pass in the button to the callback without resorting to adding an ID and using getElementById or jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript "this" keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Comment: I updated the question. Possibly not a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's an anonymous function with no binding context, and therefore `this` defaults to the global object. In your case that would be `window`.

Further reading about `this` behavior here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

**UPDATE**: Per your question edit, you can pass in a closure reference to the button:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="var self=this; ShowConfirmation('Confirm', 'Some message...', function () { SaveReleaseStage(self, 'Reassigned', 'ReleaseStage/ReassignProcess'); });" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8caMT/